# Can I get the Azure Function App default host key using Terraform?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

The function app is also created using terraform. Once it was created, I would then like to save it to a variable because I want to use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DataSource for getting host keys:

```
data "azurerm_function_app_host_keys" "example" {
  name                = "function-name"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
```

more info: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/function_app_host_keys

Comment: only problem is if you want to do this in automation, azure takes some time to create the master/default key in the app function so you may get a timeout waiting for the data to retrieve the value